# error with predict() with betareg

Tags: r

I used the `betareg()` function to determine the dynamic of my dependent variables by using a data set with 19083 rows.

```
M_Beta_F1 <- betareg(Y ~ X1+X2|1, data = data1)
summary(M_Beta_F1)
```

The fitted values are extracted via:

```
in_Y <- fitted(M_Beta_F1)
```

I wanted to determine the predicted values by using a new data set (`data2`) having 28779 rows.

```
out_Y_response <- predict.glm(M_Beta_F1, data2, type=c("response"))
```

I got the following message

```
Error in seq_len(p) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  :
  calling predict.lm(<fake-lm-object>) ...
2: 'newdata' had 28779 rows but variables found have 19083 rows 
3: In model.matrix.default(Terms, m, contrasts.arg = object$contrasts) :
  variable 'mean' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
4: In model.matrix.default(Terms, m, contrasts.arg = object$contrasts) :
  variable 'precision' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
5: In seq_len(p) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: is there a particular reason you're using `predict.glm(...)` instead of `predict(...)` ?  (The latter calls the internal `betareg:::predict.betareg()` function.)

Comment: Hievet with predict I do not get the predicted values properly:

Comment: As @BenBolker already said: You have to use the `predict(...)` generic rather than erroneously the `glm` method `predict.glm(...)`. If you believe that there is a problem with the `predict(..)` generic, please adapt your question and provide a reproducible example.